# A question about undecidable sentences with purely mathematical contents

Tags: logic, set-theory, computability, meta-math, provability

I'm struggling with the idea that the *continuum* hypothesis does indeed have a purely mathemathical/set theoretical meaning, but is neither provable nor disprovable in ZFC (according to Gödel and Cohen). Moreover, CH is not self-referential, like the Gödel and Rosser sentences are.

So why isn't it considered an example of a non-metamathematical undecidable sentence, so that we consider the Paris-Harrington sentence to be the first one with purely mathematical content? Where is my misunderstading?

Comment: P-H is a statement about _arithmetic_ whereas the CH is a statement about set theory; ZFC is a much stronger theory than (Peano) arithmetic is. Also, I would argue that 'metamathematical' is an artificial distinction; the key element of Godel's proof (IMHO) is not the self-referentiality of the sentence, but the fact that metamathematics _is_ mathematics, that questions of provability can be formulated in a purely arithmetic manner.

Comment: I couldn't agree more in respect to your comment about self-referentiality. But I still can't get the point about CH... Of course ZFC is much stronger than PA, but in ZFC we can construct lots of arithmetical systems. So why the undecidability of CH is not considered a purely mathematical one?

Comment: I'd like to see a purely mathematical definition of "purely mathematical".

Comment: I mean, I do agree that metamathematics *is* mathematics in the sense that we can treat metalinguistics questions as questions of arithmetic, but CH doesn't speak about metalinguistics issues of ZFC. Instead, it tells us that "no infinite subset of real numbers is in one-to-one correspondence with the set of positive integers, neither with the set of real numbers", a purely mathematical problem.

Comment: Knowing that other questions in stronger theories than PA are undecidable (like the Whitehead problem in group theory, or the Lebesgue-measurable projective sets problem in real analysis), and all of them have "purely mathematical" content, I tend to conclude that my misunderstanding lies on the fact that the comonsense "We still don't know any undecidable sentence with purely mathematical content" (regarding that P-H is equivalent to 'PA is consistent', thus metamathematical) is restricted to arithmetical, PA-like systems. Right? Thanks for the help, I'm really lost here... haha

Comment: What counts as "purely mathematical" is pretty much entirely a matter of opinion.  You seem to have somehow gotten the impression that CH is widely considered to not be "purely mathematical", but I would guess that is a minority view.

Comment: Yes, Eric, now I'm convinced of this. Thanks! But I still struggle with the comonsense "Paris-Harrington was the first purely mathematical undecidable sentence to be discovered". CH was proved independent of ZFC much earlier. I can only conclude what I commented in the post above yours.

Comment: I've heard claims like this made before. The meaning of "purely mathematical" the speakers use is more restrictive than merely "not based on self-reference:" rather, the focus is on statements which occur naturally in mathematics outside of mathematical logic. In that context $\mathsf{CH}$ is at best a borderline candidate: there are really very few times it's at all relevant outside of mathematical logic.  *(If that sounds rather goalpost-moving, I personally agree. But then, I'm biased - I am a logician after all.)*

Comment: If CH is not a "purely mathematical" problem I don't know what else can be given that description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notion of a "purely mathematical" statement is highly subjective. It's certainly intended to rule out sentences which arise via "encoding" techniques a la Godel/Rosser/Kleene/etc., but it may be taken further. In particular, I think reasonable people (who grant in the first place that "purely mathematical" is an adjectival phrase worth having) could disagree over whether $\mathsf{CH}$ is indeed purely mathematical. The strictest approach would be something like:

> A purely mathematical statement is one which is significant outside of mathematical logic,

and one might argue that $\mathsf{CH}$ should not be considered purely mathematical according to this criterion on the grounds that, while it does occasionally crop up outside of logic, it does so very rarely and generally indicates that a certain question isn't really the "right" one. Moreover, theorems like Shoenfield absoluteness show that in a precise sense $\mathsf{CH}$ can't have consequences for "concrete" mathematics.

By contrast, this same hypothetical one might argue, Paris-Harrington is very obviously "just" a problem of pure combinatorics. In fact, the only thing connecting it with logic is its unprovability analysis - it's not a sentence from logic, it's a sentence about which logic has a lot to say.

---

Of course all of this is highly subjective, and quite frankly I don't put much stock in the notion to begin with. But this is what's behind the attitude that $\mathsf{PH}$ has a distinguished status as a natural undecidable (in $\mathsf{PA}$ rather than $\mathsf{ZFC}$, however) sentence which $\mathsf{CH}$ lacks, which is what the OP asked.

Comment: I mean, CH is equivalent to "The global dimension of $\prod_{i\in\Bbb N}\Bbb C$ is $2$", so even if CH is "in logic", there's one that is entirely "in algebra". Whether or not it is significant is another issue.